# PHPDoc: @return void necessary?

Tags: php, return-value, phpdoc

Is it really necessary do something like this:

```
/**
 * ...
 * 
 * @return void
 */
```

I have quite a few methods that don't have a return value, and it seems really redundant to put something like this in the comment. Would it be considered bad form to leave it out?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If it makes it clear for the documentation, then leave it in, but it isn't strictly necessary. It's an entirely subjective decision.

Personally, I would leave it out.

**EDIT**
I stand corrected. After a little googling, the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) says:

> @return    [type description]  This tag **should not be used** for constructors or methods defined with a void return type.

The phpdoc.org website says:

> @return  datatype  description
> @return datatype1|datatype2 description
>
> The @return tag is used to document the return value of functions or methods. @returns is an alias for @return to support tag formats of other automatic documentors
>
> **The datatype should be a valid PHP type** (int, string, bool, etc), a class name for the type of object returned, or simply "mixed". If you want to explicitly show multiple possible return types, list them pipe-delimited without spaces (e.g. "@return int|string"). If a class name is used as the datatype in the @return tag, phpDocumentor will automatically create a link to that class's documentation. In addition, if a function returns multiple possible values, separate them using the | character, and phpDocumentor will parse out any class names in the return value. phpDocumentor will display the optional description unmodified.

Sooo... Based on that, I would say leave out the void. It's non-standard, at least.

Comment: Does adding it even do anything? I believe in PHPDoc if you don't document a return type it automatically assumes `void` and puts it into the method signature in the docs.

Comment: @Marc W: see my edit. not only is it not necessary, it is not supposed to be used.

Comment: Might have changed since 2010 but currently phpdoc.org says: "functions and methods without a `return` value, the @return tag MAY be omitted here, in which case @return void is implied."

Comment: @TFennis Thanks. I'll leave the legacy quote as-is, but it seems phpdoc is simply being more tolerant of how many developers were using it. I notice the wikipedia page is now saying [citation needed] for the statement about avoiding `@return void`.

Comment: From my point of view this answer is outdated. The type `void` is since PHP 7.1 a valid  return type and as @tivnet points in the answer below it's also a valid type for phpDocs according to phpDocumentor.

Comment: Check https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md, perhaps it changed at some point but `@return void` is even used in the examples.

Answer (score 58):

According to phpDocumentor, @return void is valid:

http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html#keywords

> ...
>   this type is commonly only used when defining the return type of
>   a method or function. The basic definition is that the element
>   indicated with this type does not contain a value and the user should
>   not rely on any retrieved value.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>  /**
>   * @return void
>   */
>  function outputHello()
>  {
>      echo 'Hello world';
>  }
> ```
>
> In the example above no return statement is specified and thus is the
>   return value not determined.

Source: http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/types.html ([archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140617130641/http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/types.html)).

Comment: This is where I point out that 'this is the correct answer'. :)

Comment: Correct answer should be changed to this.

Comment: Indeed this would be the best answer here. It is also part of PSR-5 standard that is coming up. I would go with the following approach for semantic meaningful programming: http://www.dereuromark.de/2015/10/05/return-null-vs-return-void/

Answer (score 15):

I have to edit my answer because of something I have learned recently.

Using `@return void` instead of `@return null` has a very special meaning, consider the following two examples of PHP code.

```
<?php

/**
 * @return void
 */
function return_never() {
    echo "foo";
}

/**
 * @return null|string
 */
function return_sometimes() {
    if ($this->condition()) {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

In the first example PHP will actually return `NULL`, since PHP always returns `NULL`. But the returned value is of no use to the caller since it does not say anything about what the function did. IDEs can use the documented information of `@return void` to indicate the developer that a return values is used which serves no purpose.

```
<?php

$foo1 = return_never();

$foo2 = return_sometimes();
```

The first call is senseless since the variable will always contain `NULL`, the second one might actually contain something. This is becoming even more interesting if we put the function calls into a conditional.

```
<?php

if (($foo1 = return_never())) {
    // Dead code
    var_dump($foo1);
}

if (($foo2 = return_sometimes())) {
    var_dump($foo2);
}
```

As you can see, `@return void` has its use cases and should be used if applicable.

Also note that it is going to be a part of the upcoming PHP PSR-5 standard.<sup>[1]</sup>

[1] http://www.php-fig.org/psr/

Comment: Good point, but if the function exits, it means it doesn't return `null`. Am I right? I think, in that case `@returns void` is the best option.

Comment: A function will always return `NULL` if you don’t return anything else. A function that uses `exit()` or anything like this is still returning `NULL` but you won’t receive it because PHP directly jumps to the shutdown phase ignoring your code.

Comment: Interesting. I would've assumed, if what you say is true, `finally` blocks run when I call `exit`. Not a direct correlation between the two, but it doesn't feel right. Thanks for enlightening me. :)

Comment: A better wording would have been: “[…] would still return `NULL` […]”. I guess we can compare `exit` with goto by simply telling PHP to stop executing the current code and directly jump to the shutdown phase, ignoring any code from this point on (thus goto in a more outer scope [global] than any current function is nested). A finally block is not executed, but many other functions are (e.g. `register_shutdown`, `__destruct`).

Comment: That sounds making more sense, and that's what I thought at first. I also decided to use `@returns void` to indicate that the function terminates the whole script execution, for example in a HTTP redirection. Also it would still be better to use to indicate that the function is not designed to return anything.

Comment: I had to change my answer, since I found out that `@return void` has a purpose in IDEs. Please read my edited answer and let me know if it makes things more clear.

Comment: @BartaTamás Note that it's `@return` not `@returns` for phpDocumentor ([documentation](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html))

Answer (score 8):

As of php 7.1, [`void` is a valid return type](http://php.net/manual/fr/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.void-functions) and **can** be enforced on a function.

I would **always** add it on the docblock.

Another benefit of writing it, is to differentiate the `void` methods from the methods that may return anything but don't have a `@return` entry on the docblock by negligence.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I understand and use PhpDocumentor annotations:

```
<?php

/**
 * This method always returns string.
 * @return string
 */
public function useCase1()
{
    return 'foo';
}

/**
 * This method returns 2 data types so list them both using pipeline separator.
 * @return string|false
 */
public function useCase2()
{
    if ($this->foo === 1) {
        return 'foo';
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * This method performs some operation and does not return anything so no return
 * annotation is needed.
 */
public function useCase3()
{
    $this->doOperation();
    $this->doAnotherOperation();
}

/**
 * If condition passes method returns void. If condition does not pass it returns
 * nothing so I think that specifying the return annotation with void is in space. :)
 * @return void
 */
public function useCase4()
{
    if ($this->foo === 1) {
        $this->doOperation();
        return;
    }
    $this->doAnotherOperation();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think the big thing missing from this is that documenting a function returns at all is important.  Currently standards dont have any documentation for functions that never return....hence a return void is way of saying yes this function does actually return.

Consider this code block

```html
<?php

/**
 * @return void
 */
function return_void() {
    echo "foo";
}

/**
 * @return null|string
 */
function return_sometimes() {
    if ($this->condition()) {
        return "foo";
    }
}

/**
* This function actually doesnt return at all - it kills the script
**/
function noreturn() {
     //do somthing then
     die(); //or exit()
}
```

Clearly the use of @return at least indicates the function does return