# PHP method return without value

Tags: php, oop, return

I'm in a phase of migrating to 100% OO php and I end up with lots of questions like these. So excuse me if you find it stupid, I'm just trying to make my OO programming practices good in the start so that I don't have to fix them later.

Is it OK to do this?

```
private function _some_funct($args) {
    // Some code here....
    if ($something) return;

    //Rest of code
}
```

Basically, there are 2 questions here.

1. Is it OK to use **return** with no value after it? I use it a LOT and haven't encoutered any drawbacks, but never saw it in somebody else's code. I only saw **return false**.
2. Is stopping functions this way OK generally or should I rethink my program's structure?

Example of using this would be CMS I'm making.

```
public function _init_engines() {
    $this->_session_engine = $this->_dep['SessionEngine'];
    $this->_login_engine = $this->_dep['LoginEngine'];
    if ($this->_dep['User'] == false) return;   
    $this->_security_engine = $this->_dep['SecurityEngine'];
    //Other engines go here.......
}
```

So I let system start session and setup session vars, then check if user is logged in. If user isn't logged in LoginEngine takes care of that and loads 'Login' module. Once Login module is loaded, I don't want other engines to be instantiated since they are not needed. I could have used *die* or *exit* but that would stop whole script from executing. Like this, My script finishes executing, and other things that aren't engines, like benchmarks and some other stuff still get executed which is just what I want. Again, should I reconsider my logic here or is this way OK in your opinion?

Comment: It's perfectly OK to use empty returns to get out of a function, but I generally do that only if said function is a `void` function (ie: wouldn't otherwise return anything), and can't be restructured like Ray says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return` with no value is OK if:

1. You interface says that explicitly - docblock states `@return void` (if no result value needed in the function) or something like `@return sometype|null` where `sometype` is `string`, `int`, etc.
2. Code that uses return values from such functions/methods checks `isset()` before using the returned value - this can lead to bugs if people using your code (or yourself) forget to check it.

`return` with no value is NOT OK if:

1. Error occured - use exceptions instead. Exceptions are much more easier to deal with because you can:

   1. catch them anywhere in the outer scope, even globally
   2. pass nice error messages
   3. extend exception classes to provide additional functionality
   4. check exactly what type of exception was thrown
2. Some particular result type is expected - in that case you may consider some default "empty" result or, again, use exceptions if something gone wrong - it is still much better than `isset` because it is harder to forget - exception is a "loud" way to say that an error occured.

And please, don't ever use `die()` or `exit()` to "handle" errors - it is a very bad practice to show technical details of errors to users.

As for your `_init_engines()` method - it is really hard to say if it is right or wrong without knowing the rest.

If you are interested in good examples of OOP in PHP, I would suggest looking at [Symfony](http://symfony.com/).

Comment: `@return void` is not considered a valid return type in php **[read more here](https://code.garyjones.co.uk/why-return-void-is-wrong)** or this SO answer **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29793008/1697459)** or **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061559/1697459)**

Comment: Re @Wilt comment, the first link is broken, the second has been updated to show there is now an official RFC for void type in PHP https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type

Comment: @James, thanks for your comment. My comment is 4 years old, so I guess things have changed... I will have to do some new reading on what is considered valid today.

Comment: For others reading these comments, check [the docs on **void return type** shared by @James](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type), apparently in PHP 7.1 returning void types is implemented and considered valid.

Comment: @Wilt wasn't picking you out as there's no fault, things change, was just issuing an update :)

Comment: @James, exactly! No offense taken, just adding a correcting comment for other readers :D

Answer (score 0):

This delves into the single return point vs. multiple return point religous battle, but her we go...

Using many returns without any value or real need for as execution flow control to avoid continuing in functions is pretty poor form.  It's sort of in the magic 'goto' statement camp.  Yes you can do it, but I'd vote no to actually doing it especially if it's not just a few returns early on to short circuit out of your function for a couple common cases.

Why not restructure your function so it has no return, but doesn't execute code it doesn't need to?
If you find your functions/methods to large to easily restructure, it's probably a signal that means you might want to break them into smaller more concise methods/functions.

```
  public function _init_engines() {
    $this->_session_engine = $this->_dep['SessionEngine'];
    $this->_login_engine = $this->_dep['LoginEngine'];
    if ($this->_dep['User'] != false){ 
         $this->_security_engine = $this->_dep['SecurityEngine'];
    } else if (){
       //Other engines go here.......
    } 
    //no useless return needed
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, there's no drawback in using `return;`. You usually see `return false;` because it's usually preferable to return something meaningful, when possible, to determine what the function did. If you are in the condition of "whatever it did, it's ok", then `return;` is perfectly acceptable.

Regarding the multiple return, I prefer using multiple exit points when conditions are sufficient to determine that the execution should not continue. For example, if you require a `User ID` and you don't receive one, maybe there is no point in checking the rest of data. In such case, you might end the function immediately with something like `return RES_INVALID_USERID`.  In such case I prefer multiple `return` than a chain of `if..else` (even worse when they are nested).