# Implicit void return in PHP 7.1?

Tags: php, standards, php-internals, php-7.1

I found in here the new spec: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type

```
function lacks_return(): void {
    // valid
}
function returns_nothing(): void {
    return; // valid
}
function returns_void(): void {
    return void; // valid
}
```

Ask: Do you know what happens behind the scene. Will the `lacks_return` function return actually `void`?

Comment: `Is this function also returning implicit void?` - yes

Comment: NULL http://ideone.com/AXErws or https://3v4l.org/RJRoR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have tested this yourself pretty easily:

```
function lacks_return(): void {
}

function returns_nothing(): void {
    return;
}

echo gettype(lacks_return()); // NULL
echo gettype(returns_nothing()); // NULL
```

So the answer is yes - there is an implicit empty (null) return so you could either use an empty return or skip it completely. Which kind of makes sense - returning nothing is the same as not returning anything?

Comment: `var_dump` would be better than `echo` for this example

Comment: please  also consider the new void type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792827/void-as-return-type. This looks like the main course. I was really looking for some debugging, something from the symbol table or PHP AST explanation. But this is also great bacuska.

Comment: @RobbieAverill gettype() returns a string, why var_dump() a string? :)

Comment: Sorry - I posted this when I thought it was `echo lacks_return()`, did you edit it? I may have been dreaming :)

Comment: I originally accepted your answer @DenisMysenko, I realized it is not fair to alter this since I experienced that over time.

Answer (score 5):

Behind the scenes, PHP [checks for `return` statements in `void` functions](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/dfd776b32656e573bea6141d63df6f05a396e69f/Zend/zend_compile.c#L2315-L2328) and, if they specify a return value, throws a compile-time error:

```
/* `return ...;` is illegal in a void function (but `return;` isn't) */
if (return_info->type_hint == IS_VOID) {
    if (expr) {
        if (expr->op_type == IS_CONST && Z_TYPE(expr->u.constant) == IS_NULL) {
            zend_error_noreturn(E_COMPILE_ERROR,
                "A void function must not return a value "
                "(did you mean \"return;\" instead of \"return null;\"?)");
        } else {
            zend_error_noreturn(E_COMPILE_ERROR, "A void function must not return a value");
        }
    }
    /* we don't need run-time check */
    return;
}
```

Otherwise, compilation of `void` functions works like normal. [`return` without a value implicitly returns `NULL`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/dfd776b32656e573bea6141d63df6f05a396e69f/Zend/zend_compile.c#L4161-L4163):

```
if (!expr_ast) {
    expr_node.op_type = IS_CONST;
    ZVAL_NULL(&expr_node.u.constant);
```

And every function [is compiled with an implicit `return` at the end](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/dfd776b32656e573bea6141d63df6f05a396e69f/Zend/zend_compile.c#L5607):

```
zend_emit_final_return(0);
```

[Whose return value is `NULL`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/dfd776b32656e573bea6141d63df6f05a396e69f/Zend/zend_compile.c#L2382-L2387):

```
zn.op_type = IS_CONST;
if (return_one) {
    ZVAL_LONG(&zn.u.constant, 1);
} else {
    ZVAL_NULL(&zn.u.constant);
}
```

Comment: So the compile time error will prevent bad practices returning non `void` if the function is `void`? Right?