# What is the meaning of " ( void * ) " in : if ( test == ( void * ) -1 )

Tags: c, posix, ipc

The function returns -1.

However, what is the meaning of `(void*)` in the following code:

can it work without it ?

```
test = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);

if (test == (void *)-1) {
    /* handle shmat failure */
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like portable C to me. Could you add more tags?

Comment: @Bathsheba posix...

Comment: bro void means Empty value. more reference checkout:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792827/void-as-return-type

Comment: @kannu-- `void` and `void *` are two different things. I thought that you couldn't comment until you had at least 50 rep....

Comment: @kannu : The language is different, so as the concept.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`shmat` has the following prototype:

```
void *shmat(int shmid, const void *shmaddr, int shmflg);
```

i.e. it returns a pointer to `void`, not an integer.

On error it will return *the integer -1 cast to a pointer to void*. From Linux manpages [shmat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmop.2.html):

> On success, `shmat()` returns the address of the attached shared memory segment; on error, `(void *) -1` is returned, and `errno` is set to indicate the cause of the error.

That is how you *must* do the comparison properly to check for an error return. The C11 standard says the following about the operator `==` in [6.5.9p5-6](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9p5):

> 5 Otherwise, **at least one operand is a pointer**. If one operand is a pointer and **the other is a *null pointer constant*, the null pointer constant is converted to the type of the pointer**.
>
> **If one operand is a pointer** to an object type **and the other is a pointer** to a qualified or unqualified version of void, the former is converted to the type of the latter.
>
> 6 Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.109)

That is, the standard defines behaviour for exactly 2 conversions: either one operand is a pointer to void, and the other operand is a pointer to something else; or one operand is a pointer, and the other operand is the null-pointer constant (i.e. 0, or (void*)0, or so). Since `-1` without casts is *neither* a null-pointer constant, nor a pointer, the standard doesn't specify any behaviour for such case, thus the behaviour is undefined ["by the omission of any explicit definition"](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#4).

`test == -1` is wrong, and `test == (void *) -1` is right(ish).

As it turns out this is still a grey area. `-1` is an `int` and on *my* computer, it is 32 bits. The conversion of an integer to pointer is defined by the implementation. The [GCC manuals say](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html#FOOT2):

> A cast from pointer to integer discards most-significant bits if the pointer representation is larger than the integer type, **sign-extends**[2] if the pointer representation is smaller than the integer type, otherwise the bits are unchanged.

With footnote 2 saying

> Future versions of GCC may zero-extend, or use a target-defined ptr_extend pattern. Do not rely on sign extension.

Thus it would mean that `(void *)-1` might become incorrect too; the safer way would be to write it as `(void *)(intptr_t)-1`.

---

For some reason the `(void *)0`, i.e. the null pointer, is not used to signal an error condition (even though use of such a pointer in C would be erroneous standard-wise).

Comment: Historically, it used to be possible to map the zero page (so that `(void *) 0` turns into a valid address at which objects can be placed. This is why `mmap` does not return `NULL` on failure. I do not know if this applies to `shmat` as well, but it could be the reason for this behavior.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Correct, this is also possible today with linux (on some installations you might have to adjust `/proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr` before)

Comment: Should it not be `test == (void *) -1L` or even `test == (void *) -1LL` on 64-bit systems?

Comment: @chqrlie the conversion is implementation specified... who knows :D

Comment: @chqrlie ok, added more information.

Comment: The C Standard has this language: ***6.3.2.3 Pointers** [...] An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.*

Comment: My point is that while GCC currently does it that way, it doesn't guarantee sign extension (in the future).

Comment: The man pages for `mmap` and `shmat` only mention `(void*)-1`, `clang` happens to implement `(void*)-1` as `(void*)(inptr_t)-1` and I suppose all Posix compliant compilers must do the same for the specification to stay consistent.  Interesting corner case.

Comment: I suppose one could check `errno` instead of trying to decode an error state out of the returned pointer. Note that `errno` is only set on error, so you would have to explicitly clear it before calling `shmat`

Answer (score 2):

It is [type casting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm).

The function `shmat()` returns a `void*`, so type casting is used to convert -1 (`int`) to the correct type (`void*`).

Actually, yes it could work but you'll get some warnings from the compiler.

Never ignore warnings they can hide bugs.

Comment: "*... you'll get some warnings from the compiler*" are you sure?