# What is the point of assigning the return value of a void method to a variable?

Tags: php, methods, iterator, return-type

```
class test {
    public function hello() {
        echo "hello!";
    }
    public function assign() {
        $var = $this->hello();
        $this->hello(); //both seem to be doing the same thing
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example of a piece of code that I am talking about, which is here on line 43: https://eval.in/988393

What is the point of a assigning a method call (I guess this is how it is called) to a variable and what is the explanation of this causing it to get run (it does not just assign it but it executes the code).

PS: This is actually related to Iterators like here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php . Somebody told me this:

"The point with iterators is that you do not care how the methods are called,
you only care about each single method separatly".

What did this person mean?

Comment: the scope of $var is quite different to $this

Comment: That is not assignement to a function it is about retrieving the functions return value, which in your case is not there because the function only echo's a line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, in your example and the linked example of the iterator, assigning the return value is unnecessary.

- In your example it is because there is no return value. In other words, the function returns `void` which will cause `$var` to be `null`. In general, if a function contains no `return` statement at all or only a `return;` (note that there is no variable being returned), it is useless to store the result in a variable.
- In the iterator example it is unnecessary, because the value isn't used. But the `$current` variable does still contain the actual value of the current iteration - it is not `null` (except when the array contains `null`, obviously). Actually calling `$this->current()` wouldn't be necessary at all in the iterator implementation - it looks like it is done solely for the purpose of getting the nice output of `echo "current: $var\n";` when checking for the validity.

There have been other questions asked about `void` return types in the past as well, e.g. [Void as return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792827/void-as-return-type).

---

By the way, if your question was also about storing a function in a variable (and not its result), then you probably meant something like this:

```
function foo() {
    echo 'bar';
}

$var = 'foo';
$var(); // outputs: bar
```

But be careful with these kinds of function invokations, there are quite some pitfalls coming with them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point of assigning a [`void`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type) method/function to a variable.

You will only need to assign a function that [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) a value, not a function that return nothing or just echo the output to the buffer.

Assume that you have a function that return some data from a database, so instead of re-querying your database in each function calling you will return -cache so to speak- the returned data into a variable to perform some action on it later as long as this data did not changed.

```
function foo() {
    return [1, 8, 5, 2, 1, 0, 51];
}

$variable = foo();

// sort $variable instead of foo();
// unique $variable instead of foo();
// sum $variable instead of foo();
// ... and so on
```