# Which @return type should I use for a function which returns HTML in phpDoc?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a PHP function which returns HTML like so when called:

```
public function my_function() { ?>
    <div class="somehtml">something</div>
<?php }
```

When adding a [phpDoc](https://phpdoc.org/) comment, what should I specify as the [@return](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html) type?

There is a [list of types](http://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/types.html) here but not sure which returned HTML would be classed as?

Comment: This code does not return anything.

Comment: This function doesn't return anything. It prints the HTML.

Comment: Ahh then I am confusing returning with printing. Is there an equivalent tag for this or would I just set @return to void?

Comment: Maybe if there is no equivalent for a function which prints HTML I should include `@return void Prints HTML`, so adding the description to the end?

Comment: [Just don't put any `@return` at all in this case.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2061559/965834) Simply describe what it does on the first part of your phpDoc segment.

Comment: You should rather add `: void` to signal that a function doesn't return anything. Requires that you don't use legacy PHP 5 though.